# Select date fields for only 6 months beginning with current in Drupal Views

Tags: drupal, view

I have a content type with a date field which can have multiple values.

How can i select the dates in Views for each month separately, beginning with the current month and have table columns titled with the month names?

Answer (score 0):

Views can filter the appropriate nodes easily enough using "filters" and "sort criteria" in the views UI.

But, you probably won't be able to get a table-based view of the nodes in table form without developing a custom module or theme function to render the table HTML. There's really no easy way (that I know of) to turn a specialized query into an HTML table without digging into PHP and iterating through query results.

More info on developing modules is at http://drupal.org/node/508

Answer (score 0):

And is it posible to do it by selecting the date field six times and passing six arguments?